# jQuery: when using the on .scroll event and alert firefox seems to infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, alert

I have the following jQuery code in one of my master templates:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();
    alert(scroll_top);
    if (scroll_top <= 70) {
        $('#fixedback').fadeOut(500);
    } else {
        $('#fixedback').fadeIn(500);
    }
});
```

When the code executes Firefox 11 and 12 will blank the page and become unresponsive.  I have to terminate the process in Task Manager.  If I take out the alert(), the code executes perfectly.  If I add an alert in any of the .scroll functions the same thing happens on any of my pages.  The page will load and works until I scroll the page.

Using Jquery 1.7.1.min. and C# ASPX pages. I haven't tested on other browsers as it is only for development that I need the alerts to work.

Comment: Are you saying the code works fine in FF if the alert is removed?

Comment: Yes.  If I take out the alert, the code works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Firefox.

The question: [Firefox scrollTop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033478/firefox-scrolltop-problem) has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034197/492145) that can be applied here. What it suggests is that you defer the `alert()` call using `setTimeout()` to give Firefox a chance to do whatever it needs to do to avoid blanking the page. Applying the workaround to your code, you would get something like this:

```
window.onscroll = catchScroll;
var timeOutId = 0;
var jitterBuffer = 200;
function catchScroll() {
    if (timeOutId) clearTimeout(timeOutId);
    timeOutId = setTimeout(function () { DoStuffOnScrollEvent() }, jitterBuffer);
}

function DoStuffOnScrollEvent() {
    var scroll_top = $(document).scrollTop();
    alert(scroll_top);
    if (scroll_top <= 70) {
        $('#fixedback').fadeOut(500);
    } else {
        $('#fixedback').fadeIn(500);
    }
};
```

Or, instead of `alert()`, you could use `console.log()`, which will work natively in later versions of IE and Chrome, and Firefox via [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: Love the work around.  And the explanation of what is going on, makes great sense.  Thank you.