# Why the scrollTop in jQuery doesn't work on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have this in my heading in my html file. The purpose of the code is to have an element (#hello) fade as the user scrolls the page. This is working as expected in Chrome, Safari and Opera, but the fade does not work in Firefox. Anyone know what is stopping it from performing the same way in all browsers?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scrollFromTop = $("body").scrollTop();
            $("#hello").css("opacity", 1.5-scrollFromTop/250);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What version of Firefox? You may have to use the `-moz-` prefix. References: [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/) [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity)

Comment: Can you make an jsfiddle sample ?

Comment: Firefox 30.0. -moz- prefix is for much older versions, correct?

Comment: Can you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: @mdurban Actually yes, that's a very valid point. I think `opacity` has been supported from like Firefox 0.9+ so that should be fine...

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?  If it's choppy, it could be because Firefox fires scroll events differently than other browsers.  Could [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353820/jquery-when-using-the-on-scroll-event-and-alert-firefox-seems-to-infinite-loop) address your problem?

Comment: @War10ck - I'm quite sure `opacity` is pretty much one of the *standard* CSS property that a browser must have.

Comment: @RyanMitchell I mean it doesn't work by it doesn't seem like an JS is even happening. In the other three browsers I've tried, the element gradually disappears. In Firefox, it seems like absolutely nothing happens to the element as I scroll (no change in opacity).

Comment: More discussion here: http://blog.c-krylatov.com/2013/05/05/make-sure-that-scrolls-jquery-event-will-work-everywhere/

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 For modern browsers yes, but check the first reference above for support in legacy browsers. It's not as common as you would think. Prefixes were quite common...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use : `$(document).scrollTop();`

[scrollTop() returns 0 in Firefox, but not in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941150/scrolltop-returns-0-in-firefox-but-not-in-chrome)

Like this :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scrollFromTop = $(document).scrollTop();
            $("#hello").css("opacity", 1.5-scrollFromTop/250);
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Live demo.](http://jsbin.com/zocox/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks Hors! Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your script tag with `</script>`

Comment: Sorry, it is closed. I'm having trouble getting SO's editor to not cut it off

Answer (score 0):

`$("body").scrollTop()` doesn't work in firefox.  Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776544/jquery-scrolltop-firefox-not-working), try `$(window).scrollTop()` ([see jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/JW268/2/)):

```
$(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scrollFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      $('#hello').html(scrollFromTop);
      $("#hello").css("opacity", 1.5-(scrollFromTop/250));
   });
});
```