# scroll eevent and scrollTop not working in firefox

Tags: javascript

I want to get the [**scrollTop**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop) value on scroll event.

Works good on Chrome but not on firefox.
What is the way to get this, crossbrowser/vanilla JS?

```
var i = 0;
window.onscroll = function () {
    var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    console.log(scrollTop,i); // always 0, (i works as expected)
    i++;
};
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yefLv/)

P.s.- I don't think a setTimeout is a good practise/solution for this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox scrollTop problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033478/firefox-scrolltop-problem)

Comment: @putvande, i did read that answer from 2011. I don't think a `setTimeout` is a good practise/solution for this...

Comment: @Adeneo? I was reading happy your answer and it disapeared...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
var doc = document;
window.onscroll = function () {
    var scrollTop = doc.documentElement.scrollTop || doc.body.scrollTop;
    console.log(scrollTop,i);
    i++;
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement